# HTML - How to auto refresh the messages of a Chat-App

Tags: django, django-templates, chat, refresh

I'm working on a Chat-App with Django in Python.
I tried some changes to auto refresh the messages of a chat but I had some problems:

First time I tried: I used a javascript reloader for the div of the chat (but doing this, the send-message text input clears every time the auto refresher plays.)
Second problem: the chat reset the height of the scroll every time the auto refresher plays.
So I'm looking for a solution to refresh only the chat and keeping the scroll, without affecting other elements such as the text input.

Here's the `"chats.html"` file:

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100" style="posistion:absolute; margin-left:60;">
    <div class="row justify-content-center h-100">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-xl-3 chat">
            <div class="card mb-sm-3 mb-md-0 contacts_card" style="max-height:700;min-height:700">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="" class="form-control search">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text search_btn"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body contacts_body">
                        <ui class="contacts">
                            {% for group in groups %}
                            <a href="/chats/{{ group.event_name }}/" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                {% if group.event_name == current_group.event_name %}
                        <li class="active">
                            <div class="d-flex bd-highlight" >
                                <div class="img_cont">
                                    <img src="{{ group.event_img.url }}" class="rounded-circle user_img">
                                    <span class="online_icon"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="user_info">
                                    <span>{{ group.event_name }}</span>
                                    <p>Kalid is online</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                                {% else %}
                                <li class="">
                            <div class="d-flex bd-highlight">
                                <div class="img_cont">
                                    <img src="{{ group.event_img.url }}" class="rounded-circle user_img">
                                    <span class="online_icon"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="user_info">
                                    <span>{{ group.event_name }}</span>
                                    <p>Kalid is online</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                                {% endif %}
                            </a>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ui>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer"></div>
                </div>
                </div>
                {% if is_specific %}
                <div class="col-md-8 col-xl-6 chat" id="the_chat">
                    <div class="card" style="max-height:700;min-height:700">
                        <div class="card-header msg_head">
                            <div class="d-flex bd-highlight">
                                <div class="img_cont">
                                    <img src="{{ current_group.event_img.url }}" class="rounded-circle user_img">
                                    <span class="online_icon"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="user_info">
                                    <span>{{ current_group.event_name }}</span>
                                    <p>1767 Messages</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="video_cam">
                                    <span><i class="fas fa-video"></i></span>
                                    <span><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <span id="action_menu_btn"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
                            <div class="action_menu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i> View profile</li>
                                    <li><i class="fas fa-users"></i> Add to close friends</li>
                                    <li><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add to group</li>
                                    <li><i class="fas fa-ban"></i> Block</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body msg_card_body" id="dvChat" style="display: flex;flex-direction: column-reverse;">
                            {% for message in messages %}
                            {% if user.id == message.2 %}
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mb-4">
                                <div class="msg_cotainer_send">
                                    {{ message.0 }}
                                    <span class="msg_time_send" style="color:rgba(0,0,0,1);font-size:11;">{{ message.1 }}</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="img_cont_msg">
                        <img src="the_img" class="rounded-circle user_img_msg">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-start mb-4">
                                <div class="img_cont_msg">
                                    <img src="{{ user_profile.avatar.url }}" class="rounded-circle user_img_msg">
                                </div>
                                <div class="msg_cotainer">
                                    {{ message.0 }}
                                    <span class="msg_time" style="color:rgba(0,0,0,1);font-size:11;">{{ message.1 }}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <form action="" method="POST">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                    <input name="sent_msg" id="sent_msg" type="text" onkeyup='saveValue(this);' class="form-control type_msg" placeholder="Scrivi un messaggio..."/>
                                    <input name="group" id="group" type="hidden" value="{{ current_group }}">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Send">
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% else %}
                <div class="col-md-8 col-xl-6 chat">
                    <center>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body msg_card_body">
                            <h1>My Party Chats</h1>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        </center>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Provide the javascript code you tried so it will be easier to suggest.

Comment: Are you using websockets? Or just a plain old fetch API endpoint?

Comment: @BR4NKO_97_ I think you must use websocket in this case since you are gonna hammer server with too many requests. Take a look at this tutorial:
https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/django-channels-websockets-chat/